# Do I need any visa for transit via Amsterdam (Beijing to Oslo via Amsterdam)?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, netherlands, norway

I am an Iranian Citizen (and Chinese residence permit) who has a Norway D-type visa (single entry). I'm going to buy a flight ticket from Beijing (China) to Oslo (Norway) with a connecting flight at "Amsterdam Schiphol Airport", with a layover of 13 hours and 20 minutes.

Beijing → Amsterdam → Oslo

In this case, do I need any type of visa in Amsterdam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this case, do I need any type of visa in Amsterdam?

No, you already have the required visa.

The Norwegen Type D visa allows you to enter the Schengen Area (in Amsterdam) and travel on to Norway (which is also in the Schengen Area).

Comment: It even allows you to leave the airport.